# AngularJS UI Router Resolve not called second time

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS UI Router Resolves for checking if the user is authentificated. But it is called only once. The first it works as it should, but when I try to enter the page again, it skips the resolve part and opens the page.

```
.state('login', {
    url: "/login/:state/:stateParams",
    templateUrl: "views/main.html",
    params: {
          stateParams: ""
       }
    })
.state('placeorder', {
    url: "/placeorder",
    templateUrl: "views/placeorder.html",
    params: {
         newOrder: {
             from: null,
             to: null,
             selectedLogType: null,
             selectedLogSubType: null
         }
    },
    resolve: {
        auth: function ($cookies, $stateParams, $location) {
            if (!angular.isDefined($cookies.get('token'))) {
                $location.path('/login/placeorder/'+JSON.stringify($stateParams.newOrder));
            }
            else {
                authService.checkToken().then(function (d) {
                if (d == false) {
                         $location.path('/login/placeorder/'+JSON.stringify($stateParams.newOrder));
                     }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

UPDATE:
I have changed it the following, and it works when there is no cookie set, but for the async function it doesnt work. When I am logged in, it doesn't work ($q.resolve part)

```
.state('placeorder', {
    url: "/placeorder",
    templateUrl: "views/placeorder.html",
    params: {
        newOrder: {
            from: null,
            to: null,
            selectedLogType: null,
            selectedLogSubType: null
        }
    },
    controller: "placeOrderCtrl",
    resolve: {
        auth: function ($q, $cookies, $timeout, $stateParams, $state) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            if (!angular.isDefined($cookies.get('token'))) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $state.go('/login/placeorder/'+JSON.stringify($stateParams.newOrder));
                });
                defer.reject();
            }
            else {
                authService.checkToken().then(function (d) {
                    if (d == false) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $state.go('/login/placeorder/'+JSON.stringify($stateParams.newOrder));
                        });
                        defer.reject();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        defer.resolve();
                    }
                });
            }
            return defer.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

Now it just doesn't resolve.

Comment: Could you please add some more details on the ui router's state hierarchy? Are you probably referencing the same state that is already active? If the controller must not be reinstantiated, it also won't resolve again.

Comment: Yes, I do... The first time I call the state, it redirects to "login", the second time I call it, it redirects to "placeorder" (without entering resolve). How to make it resolve everytime?

Comment: I am trying using reload: true when calling the state, but its not reinstantiated that way either.
$state.go("placeorder", {newOrder: $scope.newOrder}, { reload: true });

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Finally I found the solution. Thanks anyway :)

```
.state('placeorder', {
    url: "/placeorder",
    templateUrl: "views/placeorder.html",
    params: {
        newOrder: {
            from: null,
            to: null,
            selectedLogType: null,
            selectedLogSubType: null
        }
    },
    controller: "placeOrderCtrl",
    resolve: {
        auth: function ($q, $cookies, $timeout, $stateParams, $state, authService) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            if (!angular.isDefined($cookies.get('token'))) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $state.go('/login/placeorder/'+JSON.stringify($stateParams.newOrder));
                });
                defer.reject();
            }
            else {
                authService.checkToken().then(function (d) {
                    if (d == false) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $state.go('/login/placeorder/'+JSON.stringify($stateParams.newOrder));
                        });
                        defer.reject();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        defer.resolve();
                    }
                });
            }
            return defer.promise;
        }
    }
})
```